# How can I enforce derived methods to follow a certain pattern?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have this method in my base class.

```
public virtual void Close ()
{
    if (!IsOpen) return;

    Dispose();
    RaiseClosed();
}
```

I want child class to freely modify the method, but make sure it calls `Dispose()` first, then later it calls `RaiseClosed()`. They can do anything in before, after, or in between the two.

How can I enforce child classes to call `Dispose()` and `RaiseClosed()` at some point?

EDIT: I guess I didn't clarify the question well. Derived methods may do something before/after `Dispose()`, and before/after `RaiseClosed()`. So it's not sufficient to make sure it calls `Dispose()` and `RaiseClosed()` in an order because the derived methods may do something in between, or even after `RaiseClosed()`.

Comment: You just override that method in your child. In a new method you can call Dispose() and RaiseClosed() anytime.

Comment: You know the old saying: ["If you want something done right, do it yourself."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Guillaume_%C3%89tienne).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to simply not make `Close` a `virtual` method.  Instead have another method which is specifically designed to be overriden and call that from your `Close` method which itself properly enforces the variants you want

```
public void Close() { 
  if (!IsOpen) return;

  try { 
    CloseCore();
  }
  finally { 
    Dispose();
    RaiseClosed();
  }
}

protected virtual void CloseCore()
{
  // Derived types override this to customize their close
  // behavior 
}
```

Comment: But what if the derived method wants to do something after `Dispose()`?

Comment: @CookieMonster then add another method for them to customize like `ClosePostDispose`

Comment: @CookieMonster: this called "Template method" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You just need to add new virtual methods, when you need to extend functionality in derived classes.

Comment: Ok, but as I said the question, the derived method can do anything before or after `Dipose()`, and it goes the same for `RaiseClosed()`. I wanted to achieve that flexibility. Does this mean I need to create `PreDispose()`, `PostDispose()`, `PostRaiseClosed()`? But not all derived methods will use all of these, so I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: @CookieMonster if you want to absolutely enforce that your `Dispose` method is called and that code can run before and after it then there really isn't a much better way than to follow this basic outline.  It's a bit verbose but it will get the job done and is a fairly established pattern

Comment: @CookieMonster if you want to allow to do anything before _and_ after dispose. Then the only thing you are enforcing is that Dispose is called at some point. So you are not really enforcing a pattern as such

Answer (score 1):

First declare the method as not virtual in the following way:

```
public void Close ()
{
    if (!IsOpen) return;

    DoClosingStuff();

    Dispose();
    RaiseClosed();
}
```

and then make virtual the method DoClosingStuff()

```
public virtual void DoClosingStuff()
{
}
```

Comment: How that is different form [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621790/2530848)?

Comment: It is not! I saw this answer after I had posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, all you can enforce is in declaration. As Jared proposed, you could offer method templates that can be executed in your predicted frame. Another way you can circumvent this is using events, but basically the pattern is the same. You just offer hooks to add code to...

```
public event Action BeforeDispose;
public event Action AfterDispose;

public virtual void Close ()
{    
    if (BeforeDispose != null) BeforeDispose.Invoke();
    Dispose();
    if (AfterDispose != null) AfterDispose.Invoke();
    RaiseClosed();
}
```

That way you can restrict the kind of delegate type that can be performed in your Template and Child classes can handle these events or just ignore them. Although, I don't think that there's an advantage to this approach over Jared's...